# Using multiple table joining display item by group name, also display those are not matched

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning complex query, I also know PL/SQL. But today I really faced a big problem. I never use it anywhere. I hope image will be easy to understand. I want to display Testname, TotalCount and TotalCost. I already do that. But I want to display  other testname those are not tasted with totalCount = 0 and TotalCost = 0.

```
SELECT ts.testname
    , count(pt.id) AS TotalCount
    , sum(ts.fee)
FROM patient p
    , patientTest pt
    , testSetup ts
WHERE pt.patientID = p.id
    AND pt.testSetupID = ts.id
    AND pt.created_at BETWEEN '01/09/2017'
        AND '01/11/2017'
GROUP BY ts.testname
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've removed the invalid tags. Please tag the database you're *really* using.

Comment: You really should start using the ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins You most likely need to change those antiquated inner joins to a left outer join. As you have it coded right now you will not receive a row with a count of 0 because of the inner join.

Comment: I am using sqlserver

Comment: I added back sql-server as the screen shot is clearly from SSMS.

Comment: You also should use ANSI standard date format to avoid localization issues. BETWEEN '2017-01-09' AND '2017-01-11'

Comment: Ok. Thank you for suggestion. But is there any way to display those item which are not matched?

Comment: Yes....turn the inner join into a left outer join.

Comment: I change SQL Server to Oracle, because of the explicit mention of PL/SQL.

Comment: @Gordon The OP is just mentioning the languages he knows, that doesn't make the question about Oracle. If anything I would edit that out of the question because it's just banter and not relevant to the problem.

Comment: If you want all `Patient` - `TestSetup` pairs plus number of tests (possibly 0), first cross join `Patient` and `TestSetup` then left join PatientTest and group.

Comment: Nor Working @Serg

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess based on the information you provided. Instead of using inner joins I switched these up to left joins. Now it will still return a row for those rows that do not have a corresponding value in patientTest or testSetup. I would suggest you read up on joins and how they work. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

```
SELECT ts.testname
    , count(pt.id) as TotalCount
    , sum(ts.fee) 
FROM patient p
left join patientTest pt on pt.patientID = p.id and pt.created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-09' AND '2017-01-11'
left join testSetup ts on pt.testSetupID = ts.id
group by ts.testname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ts.testname
    , count(pt.id) AS TotalCount
    , ISNULL(sum(ts.fee), 0)
FROM testSetup ts
    LEFT JOIN patient p
        ON pt.patientID = p.id
    LEFT JOIN patientTest pt
        ON pt.testSetupID = ts.id
WHERE pt.created_at BETWEEN '01/09/2017'
        AND '01/11/2017'
GROUP BY ts.testname
```

Or if you want Distinct TotalCount use this one:

```
SELECT ts.testname
    , count(DISTINCT pt.id) AS TotalCount
    , ISNULL(sum(ts.fee), 0)
FROM testSetup ts
    LEFT JOIN patient p
        ON pt.patientID = p.id
    LEFT JOIN patientTest pt
        ON pt.testSetupID = ts.id
WHERE pt.created_at BETWEEN '01/09/2017'
        AND '01/11/2017'
GROUP BY ts.testname
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "pt.testSetupID" could not be bound.

Comment: Fixed, it was just the ON clause as I do not have the physical tables I just edited your code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT ts.testname
    , count(pt.id) as TotalCount
    , sum(ts.fee) 
FROM testSetup ts 
LEFT JOIN patientTest pt on pt.testSetupID = ts.id
   and pt.created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-09' AND '2017-01-11'
GROUP BY ts.testname
```

Looks like your original query uses no data from `Patient` but checking the patient.id exists. Provided you have FK enabled this check can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the help of @Serg.I found the solution.

```
SELECT ts.testname
    , COUNT(pt.id) AS TotalCount
    , COUNT(pt.id) * SUM(DISTINCT ts.fee) AS Total
FROM testSetup ts
    LEFT JOIN patientTest pt
        ON pt.testSetupID = ts.id
            AND pt.created_at BETWEEN '2017-01-09' AND '2017-01-11'
GROUP BY ts.testname
```

Comment: Why did you need to multiply?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/du0nlc
as example you can visit the link. 5 test take 5 * (per test price)